# C++: Address-of dereference and dereference of an address-of

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

1. Is `*&x` always equal to `x`? If not, when is it not?
2. Is `&*x` always equal to `x`? If not, when is it not?

My guess is that (1) is always true, but (2) is not always true because `x` may not always be a pointer, so we cannot state `*x`.

Comment: Look into operator overloading.

Comment: Your guess is correct (for the reason you pointed out  - get it, pointed?  :P  ).

Comment: @CaitLANJenner No and no. Remember, operator overloading.

Comment: @juanchopanza Good point. We need to know what the variable x is in this context.

Comment: In any sane code variant 1 should be `yes`. While one can overload `&`, doing so is highly frowned upon, and rightfully so. For example, I will never use a library which overloads operator `&`. Variant 2 is a different thing - overloading operator `*` is a very honored thing, used in many contexts, from smart pointers to iterators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example you get the address of `x` (which gives you a pointer to `x`) and then you deference that pointer back to `x`. So yeah it should be, unless `x` is a class that has overloaded the operators `*` or `&`.

Your second example only works with `pointers` or `classes` that have overloaded the `*` operator.

If it's used with raw pointers, yeah it should be the same. You deference `x`, which returns a reference to the value stored in `x`, and then you get the address where that value is stored, which of course is `x`.

If it's used with a `pointer` to a `class`, and the `class` has overloaded the `&` operator, then it doesn't have to be.

```
class A
{
public:
    int v;
    //int operator*()   { return v; }
    int * operator&()   { return &v; }
};

A* w = new A();
int* ptr = &*w;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes and No because `*&x` means that it is reference to a pointer meaning

   `int v1 = 10;
   int *v2 = &v1;
   int *&v3 = v2;
   cout << *v3;
   *v2 = 11;
   cout << *v3;`

will give out put 10 and 11.While declaring `*&x` does not mean get value of at address of v3.
v3 in this context is the address of the pointer it is equated to. But if you use *&x outside declaration it will give you the value stored at address of v3.

2. I belive second is illegal if & or * are not overloaded

Comment: The second one doesn't seem to be illegal when `x` is a pointer, then `&*x` simply is the address of the variable that `x` points to.